# Override * CSS style

Tags: css, overriding

In my first line I have the following style:

```
* {
    text-align:left;
}
```

Which works well through the site as most of it is *left aligned*. However a handful of areas need to be `text-align: center` and it will not update, even with `!important`. for example:

```
table.footer {
    text-align:center !important;
}
```

Any ideas on how I can fix this?

Comment: `*` has the lowest specificity in CSS, even writing `.footer` will override your `*` selector

Comment: You have to add the not working html code as well. Else it's like fishing in a barrel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should work as you can see in this [live example](http://jsfiddle.net/nK77E/).

You might want to do this instead:

```
table.footer td
{
    text-align:center;
}
```

`!important` is not needed anyway.

[**Live example**](http://jsfiddle.net/nK77E/7/)

Comment: Can be lack of `width` as well

Comment: @Mr.Alien yeah. In the last live example I added `with:100%` for the table element.

Comment: @Jason what do you mean. If you don't give us the link we can not see it :D

Comment: Oh sorry click the live example link just above, I have updated it :)

Comment: @Jason as I said, you need to add the `td` on your CSS declaration.

Answer (score 0):

I guees I know what is missing.

The table.footer selector does only match for a table with class footer, not for the elements inside it

You could do

```
table.footer td {
    text-align: center;
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/mMM5q/

or perhaps even better

```
html {
    text-align: left;
}
* {
    text-align: inherit;
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/B3F9U/